# Cryptography question - Number of passwords

Tags: combinatorics

Was just wondering whether anybody could help me with the following question:

A system accepts only passwords that contain:

• between 6 and 8 symbols: digit (0-9) or letter (a-z,A-Z);

• at least 2 letters and 2 digits;
How many passwords are accepted by this system?

My solution would be to do the following:

If there are 6 symbols then we can have:

$\ \ \ $•   2 letters 4 digits – (2+4)!/2!4!=15.   15 configurations x(52^2 x 10^4) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   3 letters 3 digits – (3+3)!/3!3!=20.   20 configurations x(52^3 X 10^3)possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   4 letters 2 digits – (4+2)!/4!2!=15.   15 configurations x(52^4 X 10^2) possibilities

If there are 7 symbols we can have:

$\ \ \ $•   2 letters 5 digits – 7!/2!5! = 21.  21 configurations x (52^2x 10^5) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   3 letters 4 digits – 7!/3!4! = 35.  35 configurations x (52^3x10^4) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   4 letters 3 digits – 7!/4!3! = 35   35 configurations x (52^4x10^3) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   5 letters 2 digits – 7!/5!2! = 21   21 configurations x (52^5x10^2) possibilities

If there are 8 symbols we can have:

$\ \ \ $•   2 letters 6 digits – 8!/2!6!= 28.   28 configurations x(52^2 x 10^6) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   3 letters 5 digits – 8!/3!5!=56.    56 configurations x(52^3x10^5) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   4 letters 4 digits – 8!/4!4!=70.    70 configurations x(52^4x 10^4) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   5 letters 3 digits - 8!/5!3!=56.    56 configurations x(52^5x10^3) possibilities

$\ \ \ $•   6 letters 2 digits – 8!/6!2!=28.    28 configurations x(52^6 x10^2) possibilities.

The answer I obtained was the addition of all of these values.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did not check the arithmetic, but the basic reasoning is sound. I am assuming that, e.g., when you write 8!/6!2!, you mean 8!/(6!2!)

Comment: I forgot to mention: you seem to have done a fine job, no help needed. Unless someone more clever than I sees a quicker way to solve this.

Comment: Thanks! I think there is a more efficient way, such as working out the total number of passwords obtainable with (52+10) 62 possibilities for every character and then taking away the passwords with 1 letter 7 digits, 7 letter 1 digits, and 8 digits and 8 letters. But I'm not sure whether this makes logical sense..

Comment: Of course, just because there are about $2^{46}$ passwords satisfying these criteria does _not_ mean that a typical password chosen to fit the criteria has 46 bits of entropy. Indeed, depending on your user base, a _very_ typical password chosen to fit these criteria might be `abc123`, which probably has less than 4 bits of effective strength (i.e. it's one of the first 16 passwords an attacker is likely to try).

Comment: On a lighter note: I so [agree with Randall Munroe.](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct and if your eight cases are added up they give 83,753,792,262,400 possible passwords.

The alternative, which you gave in your comments, would be to work out $62^6+62^7+62^8$ which is 221,918,520,426,688 (about 1.6% more than $62^8$) and subtract the eight cases failing to meet "at least 2 letters and 2 digits" worked out the same way you already have, amounting to 138,164,728,164,288 exceptions and leaving 83,753,792,262,400 allowed cases.

So two correct approaches give the same answer, as they should, and this is a good way to check.  In this particular case, your original version is probably a little faster, but in others the exclusion method may be faster or easier, e.g. if the rule was "at least 1 letter and 1 digit" or if longer passwords were allowed.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I would just say it is on the order of $62^8$.

Comment: It is about 38% of $62^8$.